# @RequestMapping not accessible

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I think I need a second pair of eyes, because I am stumped on this one.

I have a promotion page (/promotion) that has a link that goes to (/promotion/new).  This link goes to another page that allows you to create a new promotion.

What I want is when I am at **/promotion/new**, I have an "Add" button.  (Doesn't matter what the Add button does).  However, the button cannot find the @RequestMapping.

**PromoController.java**

```java
package com.mycompany.wpa.web;

// imports

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/promotion")
@SessionAttributes("promoBean")
public class PromotionController extends BaseApplicationController {

    private PromoBean promoBean;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initPromotion(Model model) {
        System.out.println("initPromotion() method called!!!!");

        // initialize 
        promoBean = new PromoBean();
        promoBean.initialize();

        // send null because we do not want to be date specific.
        promoBean.setPromoMap( priceService.getActivePromotions(null) );

        model.addAttribute("promoBean", promoBean);

        return "promotionList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createPromotion(Model model) {
        System.out.println ("createPromotion() method called!!!!");

        // initialize 
        promoBean = new PromoBean();
        promoBean.initialize();

        model.addAttribute("promoBean", promoBean);
        return "promotion";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new" params="addSku", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String addSkuToPromo(@ModelAttribute PromoBean promoBean, Model model) {

        System.out.println ("addSku new method called");

        model.addAttribute("promoBean", promoBean);
        return "promotion"; 
    }
}
```

**promotionList.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<t:wrapper>
    <jsp:attribute name="header">
        <%@ include file="../templates/header.jsp" %>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="navigation">
        <%@ include file="../templates/navigation.jsp" %>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="footer">
        <%@ include file="../templates/footer.jsp" %>       
    </jsp:attribute>

    <jsp:body>
        <h1>Promotions</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <c:url var="newUrl" value="/promotion/new" />
                <a class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;" href="${newUrl}">New</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Promotion Type</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="promo" items="${promoBean.promoMap}" varStatus="status">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="label label-primary">${promo.value.promoCategory}</span></td>
                                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${promo.value.promoStartDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" /></td>
                                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${promo.value.promoEndDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="promotion/edit/${promo.value.promoId}">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </jsp:body>
</t:wrapper>
```

**promotion.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<t:wrapper>
    <jsp:attribute name="header">
        <%@ include file="../templates/header.jsp" %>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="navigation">
        <%@ include file="../templates/navigation.jsp" %>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="footer">
        <%@ include file="../templates/footer.jsp" %>       
    </jsp:attribute>

    <jsp:body>
        <h1>Promotions</h1>

        <form:form commandName="promoBean" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form:input path="promoSku" class="form-control" placeHolder="SKU" type="text"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <form:input path="promoValue" class="form-control" placeHolder="Value" type="text"/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" name="addSku">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </jsp:body>
</t:wrapper>
```

The flow of this is when you go to **/promotion**, you are taken to a list of promotions.  On this screen, you click the link "New", and then it would take you to **/promotion/new** where it shows your a form to create a new promotion.

On this form, there is a button called "addSku" which currently does nothing.  I tried connecting it to the PromotionController.java, but it won't find it unless I remove **@ModelAttribute PromoBean promoBean** from addSkuToPromo() method.

I even tested by removing **value="/new"** from the @RequestMapping, and then put the button on the promotionList.jsp page, and it worked!... so I think there is a mapping issue and I just don't understand what it is.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='promoBean'. Error count: 2

Comment: could you share your web.xml? Did you set DispatcherServlet in web.xml?

Comment: I am using spring boot, so there is no web.xml.  I have a feeling that my problem is that I'm not understanding how RequestMapping or maybe @ModelAttribute.

Comment: I just realized that there is an error message being displayed on the browser.  I've added it above at the end.  I tried searching the error but there are no valid search results.  I'm not sure what it means.